# Django 5 postgres superuser login fail

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

I created a Django project SQLite. I decided to move from SQLite to PostgreSQL. All migrations worked. I created the superuser successfully but when I try logging in the admin it says that the user can't be found.  There are no errors
This is the users model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """
    Class for creating custom users. There are 3 user types in this class
    """
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('manager', 'Manager'),
        ('supervisor', 'Supervisor'),
        ('employee', 'Employee'),
    )

    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    # Provide a unique username or remove the unique constraint from email
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.username:
            self.username = self.name  # Use email as username or provide a unique username
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I tried logging in the admin. It says the user is not found. I used both email and username to be sure but the user still can't be found.
This is pip freeze:

```
pip freeze

asgiref==3.7.2
attrs==23.1.0
bcrypt==4.1.2
Django==5.0
django-cors-headers==4.3.1
django-filter==23.5
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.3.1
drf-spectacular==0.27.0
Faker==21.0.0
inflection==0.5.1
jsonschema==4.20.0
jsonschema-specifications==2023.11.2
Markdown==3.5.1
mysqlclient==2.2.3
psycopg2==2.9.9
PyJWT==2.8.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
PyYAML==6.0.1
referencing==0.32.0
rpds-py==0.15.2
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.9.0
uritemplate==4.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the tables manually, I found that the users were by default inactive. So i could not log in when I am not active. After editing the line and making default state of users created to True, recreating the superuser worked.